# Connecting Volt-Free probes

Tags: gpio-external-interrupt

This might be a too silly a question to ask, but I am working with the volt-free probes for the first time.

I have a probe TL2 probe that has 4 wires. The user manual states that,

> For ‘TL2’ variant, the RED and BLUE cores are the volt free pair. The
>   loop-back is across the BLACK and YELLOW cores. These connections
>   are not otherwise polarity sensitive.

I have a board that has a 2-pin connector, one of them is Digital Ground and the other one is GPIO to a microcontroller. FWI, one of the two volt-free pair has to be connected to the GPIO so that it can be used as an interrupt.

Should one of the other probe be connected to the Digital Ground, or the other two wires that are not volt-free?

Comment: what is a volt-free probe?

Comment: @jsotola  One that does not measure volts?

Comment: @jsotola: Quoting from [this](https://control.com/thread/1026171624): "A volt free contact is a contact without any voltage on it. It is usually supplied in a system for other parties to use and they then supply their own voltage into their own system eg: to a BMS system." Its not an authentic definition, but it makes sense.

Comment: volt-free seems to be a synonym for dry contact, connect it as you would a push-button or resistor.

Comment: @WedaPashi You just defined a "volt free contact".  You did not however define what a "Volt Free Probe" is.

Comment: @rdast that product is essentially the same, contacts to a reed switch

Comment: @rdast that product is essentially the same, contacts to a reed switch